# Unable to integrate sails-auth library in sails project

Tags: javascript, authentication, sails.js

I'm trying to add the sails-auth library to my sails app. after installation and running `sails lift` i get this error returned

```
debug: hookPath: /home/egwuenu/Desktop/shopper/server/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/hooks/auth
debug: marlinspike (auth): loading config from /home/egwuenu/Desktop/shopper/server/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/configdebug: marlinspike (auth): loading Services from /home/egwuenu/Desktop/shopper/server/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/services...
debug: marlinspike (auth): loading Models...debug: marlinspike (auth): loading Controllers...
debug: marlinspike (auth): loading Policies...error:
error: TypeError: sails.getBaseurl is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sails-auth library is a 3rd-party module that hasn't been updated in a few years, so it's likely not compatible with newer versions of Sails (1.0 and later).
In the spot where it's failing, it's trying to use `sails.getBaseUrl`, which is [deprecated as of Sails 1.0](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/advanced-usage/sails-get-base-url). (And looks like the capitalization was off to begin with: it's using `getBaseurl` instead of `getBaseUrl` with a capital "U", so it may not have worked even with older versions of Sails.)

For built-in auth in Sails 1.0 and later, try generating a new app with: `sails new foo --caviar`. (You can reference an example app built with that template [here](https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration).)